# How can I initiate a Remote Assistance session in .NET?

Tags: .net, winapi, rdp

I'm writing a help desk application and would like to allow my users to initiate a Remote Assistance session on a remote PC.  This can be done via Help in Windows XP, but I haven't been able to find any code sample in .NET.   Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Its actually pretty darn simple, I wrote this to allow clients to download a small exe and click a button and it generates a Remote Assistance Request ticket and opens Remote Assistance in the background. Then the file is sent to my helpdesk server by ftp and boom, I have one click access to the clients computer.

Just make sure to include a recursive kill() afterward so it doesn't leave any lingering processes in the background.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
string fileurl = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "Invitation.msrcincident";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "Msra.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/saveasfile " + fileurl + " MyPassword";
Console.WriteLine(p.StartInfo.Arguments);
p.Start();

while (File.Exists(fileurl) == false)
{
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

//CODE TO EMAIL/UPLOAD FILE HERE
```

Comment: More complete code at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289046/trying-to-hook-dialogs-created-by-a-child-process-from-parent)

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811079.aspx

You may need P/Invoke to actually access these functions.

---

On further review, there is some source on CodePlex to generate remote assistance tickets. Correct me if I'm wrong, but you are looking to generate a ticket for remote assistance on the client end.  Check out http://www.codeplex.com/RemoteAssistHelper

Comment: Thanks - I found the same article, but it doesn't provide a C# or VB code sample, which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
Remote Assistance using the MSRA Exe and its arguments.

Here I have desinged a class and a form,  and it gives you the following functionalities,

1)  Offer Remote Assistance to a Machine
2)  Ask for Remote Help. (Invite someone to help you)

Design A form with the folloiwng controls,

1)  Textbox for taking the IP or Computer name to Connect
2)  Button 1. To connect to the Remote Machine for offering Remote Assistance
3)  Button 2. To Ask or invite someone to help.




Code Behind in the Form:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace RemoteAssist
{
    public partial class FrmConnect : Form
    {
        public FrmConnect()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RemoteConnect remoteConnect = new RemoteConnect();
            Boolean status;
status = remoteConnect.StartRemoteAssistance(txtComputerName.Text.ToString(), true,false);
            if (status == false)
            {
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Unable to Connect to the Remote Machine.Please try Again later.");
            }


        }

        private void BtnInvite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RemoteConnect remoteConnect = new RemoteConnect();
            Boolean status;
            status = remoteConnect.StartRemoteAssistance(txtComputerName.Text.ToString(), false, true);

            if (status == false)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Unable to Establish Connection, Please try Again later.");
            }
        }

        private void FrmConnect_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void txtComputerName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtComputerName.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
        }             


    }
}

We have two buttons here and they are sending the Boolean variable to the class function for differentiating between offer Help and Asking for Help.


Code under the Class File : RemoteConnect


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace RemoteAssist
{
    class RemoteConnect
    {
        public Boolean StartRemoteAssistance(String strMachinename, Boolean offerHelp, Boolean askForHelp)
        {            
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();                        

            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;            
            startInfo.FileName = "msra.exe";

            // Offer Remote Assitance 
            if (offerHelp == true)
            {
                startInfo.Arguments = "/offerRA " + strMachinename;
            }

            //ASK for Remote Assistance
            if (askForHelp == true)
            {
                startInfo.Arguments = "novice";
            }

            try
            {
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
                return true;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error Occured while trying to Connect" + ex.Message);
                return false;
            }           
        }
    }
}
```