# Trying to hook dialogs created by a child process from parent

Tags: c#, .net

I've written a small utility that uses MSRA.exe to create a remote help invitation file and immediately begin listening for assistance help requests for a help desk environment. The application works great and the thread MSRA.exe operates completely invisible to the user, but the one issue I have is that if the user terminates the connection improperly by killing the process or somthing then the next time my app is run and the MSRA.exe is called it sends a dialog that says the user didn't close the last connection properly and desktop settings were not restored, do they wish to restore desktop settings now? Well since I have MSRA hidden the dialog is hidden as well and halts the MSRA program while it waits for a response, is there any way to check for this dialog and force an answer?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Management;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void EndSession()
        {
            if (button1.Text != "Launch Connection")
            {
                button1.Text = "Closing Connection...";
                this.Refresh();
                if (p.HasExited == false)
                {
                    KillProcessAndChildren(p.Id);
                }
                if (File.Exists(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "Invitation.msrcincident") == true)
                {
                    File.Delete(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "Invitation.msrcincident");
                }
            }
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void KillProcessAndChildren(int pid)
        {
            using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_Process Where ParentProcessID=" + pid))
            using (ManagementObjectCollection moc = searcher.Get())
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
                {
                    KillProcessAndChildren(Convert.ToInt32(mo["ProcessID"]));
                }
                try
                {
                    Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
                    proc.CloseMainWindow();
                    if (!proc.WaitForExit((int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3).TotalMilliseconds))
                    {
                        proc.Kill();
                    }
                }
                catch (ArgumentException)
                { /* process already exited */ }
            }
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (button1.Text == "Launch Connection")
            {
                button1.Text = "Opening Connection...";
                this.Refresh();
                if (File.Exists(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "Invitation.msrcincident") == true)
                {
                    File.Delete(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "Invitation.msrcincident");
                }

                string fileurl = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "Invitation.msrcincident";
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
                p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                p.StartInfo.FileName = "Msra.exe";
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/saveasfile " + fileurl + " MyPass";
                Console.WriteLine(p.StartInfo.Arguments);
                p.Start();

                while (File.Exists(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "Invitation.msrcincident") == false)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.MyFTP.net/" + System.Environment.UserName + "." + Dns.GetHostName() + ".msrcincident");
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MyUser", "MyPass");
                request.UsePassive = true;
                request.UseBinary = true;
                request.KeepAlive = false;
                Stream ftpstream = request.GetRequestStream();


                FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(fileurl);
                int length = 1024;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                do
                {
                    bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
                    ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                } while (bytesRead != 0);

                stream.Close();
                ftpstream.Close();
                button1.Text = "Connection Open";
            }
            else
            {
                EndSession();
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EndSession();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = System.Environment.UserName;
            textBox2.Text = Dns.GetHostName();

            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("msra");

            foreach (Process process in processes)
            {
                process.Kill();
            }

        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            EndSession();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your asking if its possible to check for a specific dialog is open, the answer is of course it is, you just have to "look" for the title of the dialog in question.  This means looking at all open windows for a period of time.

Comment: Well i would actually have to hook it too since I want to force the dialog response, since it is not visible it does no good to know if it is present or not without being able to trigger a response. I think the answer lies in hooking the message but so far documentation I have found on this is spotty at best.